# Finding value of $m$ such that such that the polynomial is factorized

Tags: polynomials, factoring

A polynomial $2x^2+mxy+3y^2-5y-2$ Find the value of $m$ much that $p(xy)$ can be factorized into two linear factors

Comment: Shouldn't it be $p(x,y)$, not just $p(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Putting $m = 7$ you obtain
\begin{align*}
(x+3y+1)(y+2x-2) &= xy+2x^2-2x+3y^2+6xy-6y+y+2x-2 \\
  &= 2x^2 + 7xy +3y^2-5y-2
\end{align*}

Comment: of course doing it that way I figured it out too ma can be 7 or -7 but the real question is what is the standard way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Solve $p(x,y) = 0$ for $x$. Roots are $q_1(y)$ and $q_2(y)$. You will obtain a representation $p = (x - q_1)(x - q_2)$. Now find $m$ that makes $q$ into linear expressions.